# Como criar elementos de formulário HTML com botão e funções javascript? e depois transformar os dados em JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estou criando um formulário simples onde após preenchido irá gerar a declaração de conteúdo dos correios e etiquetas de envio automaticamente, porém as vezes existem mais do que 1 produto a ser adicionado na declaração e para não poluir a página pensei de ter opção de cadastro para um produto e um botão para adicionar mais, se necessário. Ficará mais ou menos como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código HTML está dessa forma:

```html
<h5>Produtos</h5>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input value="Drinking horn lagarto" id="conteudo1" type="text" class="validate">
    <label class="active" for="first_name2">Produto</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s3">
    <input value="2" id="quant1" type="text" class="validate">
    <label class="active" for="first_name2">Quantidade</label>
  </div>
<div class="input-field col s3">
  <input value="125.00" id="valor1" type="text" class="validate">
  <label class="active" for="first_name2">Valor unitário</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s3">
    <input value="1.00" id="peso" type="text" class="validate">
    <label class="active" for="first_name2">Peso total</label>
  </div>
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn brown right s3" style="margin-top: 25px;" onclick=""><i class="material-icons left">add</i>Adicionar Produto</a>
</div>
```

A ideia é que ao clicar no botão **Adicionar produto** ele gere outro campo igual este abaixo do primeiro.

**Problema 2**:
Outro detalhe que está me quebrando a cabeça é de como vou montar meu objeto depois de ter o segundo elemento HTML? Porque meu Json é montado da seguinte forma com um único produto:

```js
function sendInfo(){

   var remNome = document.getElementById('remNome').value
   var remEndereco = document.getElementById('remEndereco').value
   var remLinha2 = document.getElementById('remLinha2').value
   var remCidade = document.getElementById('remCidade').value
   var remUf = document.getElementById('remUf').value
   var remCep = document.getElementById('remCep').value
   var remDoc = document.getElementById('remDoc').value
   var desNome = document.getElementById('desNome').value
   var desEndereco = document.getElementById('desEndereco').value
   var desLinha2 = document.getElementById('desLinha2').value
   var desCidade = document.getElementById('desCidade').value
   var desUf = document.getElementById('desUf').value
   var desCep = document.getElementById('desCep').value
   var desDoc = document.getElementById('desDoc').value

   var conteudo1 = document.getElementById('conteudo1').value
   var quantidade1 = document.getElementById('quant1').value
   var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor1').value)

   var peso = parseInt(document.getElementById('peso').value)

  var pedido = {
    "remNome": remNome,
    "remEndereco": remEndereco,
    "remLinha2": remLinha2,
    "remCidade": remCidade,
    "remUf": remUf,
    "remCep": remCep,
    "remDoc": remDoc,
    "desNome": desNome,
    "desEndereco": desEndereco,
    "desLinha2": desLinha2,
    "desCidade": desCidade,
    "desUf": desUf,
    "desCep": desCep,
    "desDoc": desDoc,
    "itens": [
    {
      "conteudo": conteudo1,
      "quant": quantidade1,
      "valor": valor1
    }
    ],
    "peso": peso
  };
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Peterson,

Para criar os elementos dinamicamente com Javascript, você pode utilizar o trecho de código abaixo.
Fiz algumas modificações para adicionar também um data-attribute. É uma boa prática trabalhar com data-attributes para isolar o código relacionado a manipulação de tela e o código relacionado a estilização css (como classes).

Para saber mais:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

```js
var productNumber = 1

function addRow() {
    let newRow = `    
    <div class="row" data-produto="${productNumber}">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input value="Drinking horn lagarto" data-conteudo="${productNumber}" type="text" class="validate">
            <label class="active" for="first_name2">Produto</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s3">
            <input value="2" data-quantidade="${productNumber}" type="text" class="validate">
            <label class="active" for="first_name2">Quantidade</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s3">
            <input value="125.00" data-valor="${productNumber}" type="text" class="validate">
            <label class="active" for="first_name2">Valor unitário</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input value="1.00" id="peso" type="text" class="validate">
                <label class="active" for="first_name2">Peso total</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
    document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += newRow
    productNumber++;
}
```

No seu HTML, adicione a propriedade "onclick" ao clicar no botão, para que a função seja executada ao clicar no botão:

```
<i class="material-icons left">
   <input id="btnAddRow" type="button" value="Adicionar Produto" onclick="addRow()" />
</i>
```

Quando adicionar mais produtos na tela, irá adicionar um 'data-produto={id}', 'data-quantidade={id}', data-valor={id}.
Isso irá facilitar na tratativa dos produtos.

No momento de montar o seu objeto, pode aproveitar a variável **productNumber**, que já guarda a quantidade de produtos adicionados.
Dessa forma, pode criar um loop *for* de 1 até a quantidade de produtos adicionados, e pegar os dados com base no *data-produto*, *data-quantidade*, etc.

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= productNumber; i++){
    item = {}
    item.conteudo = document.querySelector(`[data-conteudo="${i}"]`)
    item.quantidade = document.querySelector(`[data-quantidade="${i}"]`)
    item.valor = document.querySelector(`[data-quantidade="${i}"]`)

    //agora adicione esse objeto javascript ao array de itens do seu json
    pedido.itens.push(item)
}
```

Acredito que com apenas alguns ajustes consiga implementar na sua função *sendInfo()*.
Caso enfrente problemas, nos deixe saber!

Comment: a primeira parte funcionou perfeitamente com pequenos ajustes no front.

A segunda parte que se refere a pegar os dados dos produtos e montar meu objeto JSON não consegui finalizar. Nesta tenho dois problemas.

1- Já existe um campo produto antes dos novos serem criados, então quando for coletar dados preciso pegar do que já existia antes também.

2 - Quando uso essa função que me mostrou no terminal ele imprime o elemento HTML inteiro. Tentei imprimir algo como Console.log(produto.valor) etc mas sem sucesso. Depois não sei também como irei montar no objeto json.

Comment: Editei a resposta original, adicionando um método que deve ajudar na resolução do segundo problema!

Comment: Tentei usar seu método mas por algum motivo ele da como pedido não definido. Tentei colocar antes, depois do objeto pedido ser declarado e mesmo assim persiste. Tentei também adicionar um `console.log("item: "+JSON.stringify(item))` para ver o que estava vindo antes de dar o `push` mas ele retorna tudo como `null`.

Eu tentei acessar o `pedido.itens` e consigo normalmente para imprimir no console.

Engraçado que se eu criar um item dessa forma:

 `item = {
    "conteudo": "copos",
    "quant": 3,
    "valor": 100.00
  }`

E adicionar usando `pedido.itens.push(item)` funciona

Comment: Apenas caso alguém esteja com o mesmo problema: Consegui resolver o problema utilizando Jquery para pegar os valores, dessa forma deu certinho com a mesma lógica do @not_ever que ajudou muito. Obrigado!